# Magento Throwing Error Under High Loads: UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID

Tags: mysql, magento

I am trying to figure out why under high load (not under normal load) our magento store throws the following error at random intervals:

Payment transaction failed. *Reason* 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 
'INV1392428' for key 'UNQ_SALES_FLAT_INVOICE_INCREMENT_ID'

This results in the card being processed but the order not going through. My guess is that transactions are colliding on the db, (we are running InnoDB) but I cant figure out how to set it so that it "locks" the key properly to keep from duplicates being created.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: do you do any checks before hand on your values that you are using in the table?  What does your table look like?

Answer (score 0):

The increment is done in PHP (Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type::Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type()), not the database, and so there is a defined period of time where it is possible to get two of the same increment IDs.  Normally this period of time is very, very small though there are two scenarios that could increase it.

1. Extremely high database load that is slowing down save operations
2. A customization (or possibly Magento itself) that is starting a transaction earlier in the save process.  Transactions *may* lock tables and increase the window of opportunity for duplicate increment IDs to be generated.  Couple this with #1 and the window for this error to occur will increase.

Comment: Database load isnt likely. I have it running with almost 0 wait state at 100% load, 18gb ram dedicated to innodb. 24 gbs total just to mysql. Customization is a possibility. Could slow PHP performance cause this? I just noticed the server is running 5.3, which is MUCH slower than 5.4 - 5.6 with magento.

Comment: PHP 5.3 could conceivably contribute to it IF there is a significant amount of logic being executed and IF a transaction was started at one point in the request and committed a significant amount of time later on.

Comment: I have embarked upon writing my own increment model. I dug into the class you pointed me to, and saw the code generating it, and see how the error occurs. Not sure why the developers went this route, but it is what it is. My strategy is to code this so it increments by 7's and by introducing a series of checks and essentially randomized waits to try to reduce the chance of dupes.

Comment: We can actually duplicate the issue with 4 of us just sitting on the dev server and submitting the orders all at the same time. On our last super busy sales day (1st of the month) we had over 37 occurrences of this issue. With cards being billed, but transactions not going through.

Comment: I would suggest doing a debug and setting a breakpoint to see what the backtrace is and see if you are in a transaction.  If you don't have access to a debugger run debug_backtrace() and dump the results.

I also wrote a JMeter JMX that load tests the checkout.  It might help replicate the issue a little easier than having 4 people on the checkout page manually ordering things.  http://www.eschrade.com/page/load-testing-the-magento-checkout-with-jmeter/